# Kendo UI: TreeView - Is there anyway to catch an event for when a node is added?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I am trying to catch an event on a treeview with ondemand loading. The event I want to capture is when I manually add a node. What happens right now is after adding a node, the treeview makes a request to the server for children of the parent i am adding to (which I ignore to avoid duplication issues). However, I do not get any events once the node is added. I get an event (requestEnd) right BEFORE the node is added visually but none after. I thought the expand event would be thrown as well, but i am not getting that either. Is there anything I can hook into to get that event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [dataBound](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/treeview#databound) event should be thrown when new node is added to the Treeview.

Comment: dataBound does indeed inform of changes, although it would be nice if the change event (which provides more information on reasons) would do the same. Anyways, thanks.